¿Por qué al pasar el cursor sobre los puntos del gráfico muestra el argumento en vez del nombre de serie? dxchartsui:WebChartControl
Al pasar el cursor sobre los puntos en el grafico cuando solo hay un valor muestra el argumento en vez del nombre de serie
DataTable motivoDT = Teletrabajo.getMotivos();
//Initializing chart
List < Series > series = new List < Series > ();
int e = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < motivoDT.Rows.Count; p++) {

  series.Add(new Series(motivoDT.Rows[p][1].ToString(), ViewType.Line));
  txtMotivoDescripcion = motivoDT.Rows[p][1].ToString();

  if (TextMotivo.GridView.Selection.IsRowSelected(p)) {
    textMotivo = motivoDT.Rows[p]["Id"].ToString();
    // DataTable hoursSubtype1 = TimeSheet.GetComercialAbsenteeismHours(monthSelected + 1, yearSelected, typesDT, subtypesDT, comercialDT.Rows[i][0].ToString());
    DataTable hoursSubtype = Teletrabajo.GetEstadisticasTeletrabajobyMotivo(Convert.ToInt32(ASPxGridYearSelected1.Text), txtEmpresa, textMotivo);

    if (hoursSubtype.Rows.Count > 0) {
      for (int m = 0; m < hoursSubtype.Rows.Count; m++) {
        for (int c = 1; c <= 12; c++) {
          if (c.ToString() == hoursSubtype.Rows[m]["Mes"].ToString()) //&& (textMotivo == hoursSubtype.Rows[m]["MotivoId"].ToString()))
          {
            var point = new SeriesPoint(Mes[c - 1], hoursSubtype.Rows[m]["Total"]);

            //Asignar el tooltip para el punto usando string.Format
            point.ToolTipHint = string.Format("{0}: {1}", series[p].Name, hoursSubtype.Rows[m]["Total"]);

            // Agregar un nuevo punto a la serie
            // series[p].Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(Mes[c - 1], hoursSubtype.Rows[m]["Total"]));
            series[p].Points.Add(point);
            // Sumar los valores
            // totalValues[month.Value-1] += int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["Total"].ToString());
            c = 12;
          }
        }
      }
      e++;
    }
  }
}

SubtypeHourChart.Series.Clear();

